# Multiple commands in sudoers file results in syntax error

Tags: sudo

It seems to be possible to add multiple commands in the sudoers file in the following format:

```
john ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /command1, /command2
```

What I have used in the sudoers file is:

```
<username> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/deploy.sh, service tomcat8 restart
```

But saving results in:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 21 <<<
```

Where line 21 is the line with the multiple commands. I also tried to put the commands in a `Cmnd_Alias` but the same result.

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10. How can I have multiple commands in my sudoers file?

Comment: What did you actually put there?

Comment: @muru I added it

Comment: Why didn't you use the full path for `service`?

Comment: @muru Right, that works :) Thanks. Would you mind posting this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`man sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) says:

```
 A Cmnd_List is a list of one or more command names, directories, and
 other aliases.  A command name is a fully qualified file name which may
 include shell-style wildcards (see the Wildcards section below).
```

That is, you have to use the full path of commands. A bare word like `service` is an error.